# Delete all letters except the first letter of each word and keep punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have a text file named “MyTextFile.txt”. I want to delete all letters and put in their place dashes  **except the first letter** of each word, also **keep the punctuation**.

Suppose the text file “MyTextFile.txt” contains the following strings:

***The boy went to the school, then ate his breakfast!
Wow, that’s not a nice story!?***

The desired result is like this:

**T-- b--  w--  t- t-- s----- , t-- a-- h-- b------- !
W-- , t--- ’ s n-- a n--- s---- ! ?**

Here is my working, which is almost good, but not perfect!

```
import nltk
file_content = open("MyTextFile.txt", encoding='utf8').read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)
print(tokens)

first_letter = [i[0] for i in tokens]

new_words = ' '.join(first_letter).strip()
print(new_words)
appendFile = open('results_file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
appendFile.write(new_words)
```

My output is this:

**T b w t t s , t a h b ! W , t ’ s n a n s ! ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of manipulation is best done with regex:

```
import re
txt = "This is a test!"
dashed = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+)", lambda m: m[1] + "-"*len(m[2]), txt)
print (dashed)
```

Will output: `T--- i- a t---!`

And to apply it to files:

```
with open("input_file.txt", 'r') as i:
    with open("output_file.txt", 'w') as o:
        for txt in i:
            dashed = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+)", lambda m: m[1] + "-"*len(m[2]), txt)
            o.write(dashed + '\n')
```

Comment: Seriously... WOW!!

Comment: Could you do this code on a file instead of a string. I am very new to programming, and I have a superficial knowledge of Regex :)

Comment: @AkbarHussein just change `txt` to `tokens` and add this bunch of code after `print(tokens)` of you own code.

Comment: @uri-goren Your code works wonderfully, but for the sake of understanding it, the line before the last ... what is the meaning of the lambda function here??... I mean this part [lambda m: m[1] + "-"*len(m[2])]

Comment: There are 2 capturing groups in the regex, m[1] is the first

Comment: The lambda gets a match object, and should return a replacement string

Answer (score 1):

Actually, @Uri answer is way better than mine. Here it is anyway :)

```
import nltk

file_content = "The boy went to the school, then ate his breakfast! Wow, that’s not a nice story!?"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)
print(tokens)

new_words = []
for token in tokens:
    token = token.strip() 
    if token.isalpha():
        new_word = token[0]
        new_word += "-"*(len(token)-1)
    else:
        new_word = token
    new_words.append(new_word)

new_words = ' '.join(new_words)
print(new_words)
# T-- b-- w--- t- t-- s----- , t--- a-- h-- b-------- ! W-- , t--- ’ s n-- a n--- s---- ! ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to know previous character in order to do that task - `zip` will be helpful:

```
txt = "The boy went to the school, then ate his breakfast! Wow, that’s not a nice story!?"
new_txt = txt[0] + ''.join('-' if curr.isalpha() and prev.isalpha() else curr for prev, curr in zip(txt,txt[1:]))
print(new_txt)
```

Output:

```
T-- b-- w--- t- t-- s-----, t--- a-- h-- b--------! W--, t---- n-- a n--- s----!?
```

Explanation: I take `txt` and `txt[1:]` that is txt starting at 2nd character then use `zip` to create single iterable with every element consisting of two characters: `prev` i.e. previous and `curr` i.e. current, if both are letters I make `-` otherwise current character, then I join all characters I made and add first character (`txt[0]`) at start as it was considered earlier, because it do not have previous.

I think regular expressions are better suited for this task, however giving above sample I want to show that using `python` language, you can write concise code doing it without regular expressions use.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple python logic::

```
def keepPunc(x):
    temp = x[0]
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        if x[i].isalpha():
            temp=temp+"-"
        else:
            temp=temp+x[i]
    return temp



def func(a):
    temp = a.split()
    final = [i[0]+"-"*(len(i)-1) if i.isalpha() else keepPunc(i)for i in temp]
    print(a)
    print(' '.join(final))

a = "The boy went to the school, then ate his breakfast! Wow, that’s not a nice story!?"
func(a)
```

output::

The boy went to the school, then ate his breakfast! Wow, that’s not a nice story!?

T-- b-- w--- t- t-- s-----, t--- a-- h-- b--------! W--, t---’- n-- a n--- s----!?

Comment: It assumes that the first letter of every word is alpha, but you can tune it in function keepPunc(x), by modifying temp and further logic a bit.